# -ios i want to register iphone's device_token in DB. But sometimes that happens fail

Tags: ios, devicetoken

I made my app to register iPhone's device_token when app launch for the first time after installed. But sometimes that happens fail.
 but app needs device_token for operating ordinarily.

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{

NSString * useruuId = [AppDelegate getUUID];
NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];

token = [token stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{

        NSString * postBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=%@&token=%@",useruuId,token];

        NSString * endpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@device_register.php",APNSPATH ];
        NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:endpoint] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:kRequestTimeInterval];

        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
        request.HTTPBody = [postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSError * error = nil;
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response;

        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        //NSLog(@"statusCode(device_register.php):%ld",response.statusCode);

        if(response.statusCode== 200)
        {

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kRegisteredID];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            break;
        }

});
```

}

I know [didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken] method is called only once operating after app installed.
So If I fail to register device_token to Server in  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken , I can't get device_token by next time. so I can't register token in server.

how i get device_token when failed ?
Additionally , is there a case app fail to get device_token from apple's server? 
If it is, how i get device_token ?

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to enable push notification in you provisional profile. Then you have to use following code for getting device token.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
      NSString *yourDeviceToken = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
      yourDeviceToken = [yourDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
      NSLog(@"your device token: %@", yourDeviceToken);
}
```

Lets try using this